# JS for textarea in HTML form - POST request not sending textarea

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am using pure JS to add options to a textarea, namely using SunEditor.

The JS is rendered in the front-end's textarea tag, but the input/content created is not being saved/POSTed to the the server via the form's POST request.

Can someone please point me where am I going wrong?

```html
<textarea id="w3review" name="w3review"></textarea>
<script>
    const editor = SUNEDITOR.create('w3review', {
        font: ['Arial'],
        buttonList: [['font', 'fontSize']],
        callBackSave: function(contents) {}
    });

    const contents = editor.getContents();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The textarea does not have a `name` attribute, this is required for POST requests. the `id` attribute is primarily for JavaScript.

Try this for your textarea:

`<textarea id="w3review" name="w3review"></textarea>`

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I do have a name attributeI am using a page builder and it's inputted in the UI so I  forgot to add it here,( edited now).

I think there is a problem with JS forwading the input upon form submission.

Comment: Can you provide the code of the POST request being sent, and the PHP code that is receiving it?